# Is there a way to store images directly into Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know how to upload images from android studio to be uploaded into the Firestore, is there a way to do it directly?

Answer (score 1):

To write an image to Firestore, include an array of bytes (`byte[]`) in your calls to [`DocumentReference.set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference) (or `DocumentReference.update()`).

In general though, I'd recommend looking at [Cloud Storage for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start) to store images in Firebase, as it's a dedicated file storage product.